# Add an Asterisk Every Time a Number shows up in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, format

I have a program that basically needs to randomize a bunch of numbers in an array and then calculate the amount of times a number within a range is found. It would then print out, for example,

```
0     | ***

1-10  | ************

11-20 | **********

21-30 | *********

31-40 | **************

41-50 | *********
```

My problem is that I can't put the numbers into a range, so I put some makeshift range into my code below to show you guys what I am trying to do:

public class arrays {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numbers[]=new int[50];
    String asterisk = "*";
    String asterisk1 = "*";
    String asterisk2 = "*";
    String asterisk3 = "*";
    String asterisk4 = "*";
    String asterisk5 = "*";
    for (int i = 0; i <= numbers.length; i++)
    {
        numbers [i] = (int)(Math.random()*50);
        if (numbers = 0)
        {
            asterisk += 1;
        }
        if (numbers >= 1 && numbers >= 10)
        {
            asterisk1 += 1;
        }
        if (numbers >= 11 && numbers >= 20)
        {
            asterisk2 += 1;
        }
        if (numbers >= 21 && numbers >= 30)
        {
            asterisk3 += 1;
        }
        if (numbers >= 31 && numbers >= 40)
        {
            asterisk4 += 1;
        }
        if (numbers >= 41 && numbers >= 50)
        {
            asterisk5 += 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.format("%0s, %6s, %8s", "0", "|", asterisk);
    System.out.format("%0s, %6s, %8s", "1-10", "|", asterisk1);
    System.out.format("%0s, %6s, %8s", "11-20", "|", asterisk2);
    System.out.format("%0s, %6s, %8s", "21-30", "|", asterisk3);
    System.out.format("%0s, %6s, %8s", "31-40", "|", asterisk4);
    System.out.format("%0s, %6s, %8s", "41-50", "|", asterisk5);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

To give you a little nudge, you do not seem to be saving the randomized numbers in the array. You set them to a variable inside of the loop, which does not live beyond the loop.

Also, your array is set to hold 51 integers, but your loop will only insert the first 50. That is not necessarily going to break your program, but it is good to make sure all of your numbers match up.

As for the counting, your buckets seem to be in groups of ten, so some math based on what "tens" value the number in question contains would be a good step. I do not just want to hand you the algorithm, as learning to solve these problems is pivotal for your continued growth as a developer.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on your explanation? Sorry, I am very novice at this but I want to get better :)

Comment: In your for loop (starting on line 4 above), you have a single line of code (line 6). That line of code generates a random number between 1 and 50 and stores it in a variable named random. Since nothing else is done with that variable, the value in it is lost at the end of the loop's execution. Your first correction is to make sure you assign the appropriate index in your array (your i variable actually contains that index) to the random number. In order for this to make any sense, you have to understand the nature of for loops and arrays. If you do not, I suggest looking at those first.

Comment: So I can system print each number, and it shows each one separately, but now how would I basically say "if next number =>1 && <= 10, print out an asterisk" This is the biggest problem I am facing atm, but I thought i could maybe use a for loop to determine what the number is, then maybe place it into one of the ranges, but how would I do that?

Comment: There are a number of different strategies, but you are probably going to want to count the occurrences before you do any printing, since you need to know how many asterisks to print for each bucket before you print the next bucket. Keeping track of that count could be done in a second integer array, potentially, with index 0 being for 1 - 10, index 1 being 11 - 20, etc. That is just one possibility.

Comment: so then how would i make it so that "if next number = index 0, print out asterisk" because I like the route youre going :D

Comment: By the time that second array is completed, you no longer need to know the values. If index zero's value is four, that means you encountered four values in between one and ten. That means you need four asterisks for that bucket.